# Is it possible to set the placeholder pseudoelement text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know it's possible to *style* the placeholder of an HTML element using the `::placeholder` CSS pseudo-element.

E.g.

```
input[type="text"]::placeholder {
 ... /* style rules */
}
```

But is it possible to *set the text* of the placeholder in CSS?

```
input[type="text"]::placeholder {
 content: "Common placeholder for all inputs" /* content rules */
}
```

Comment: If you can script CSS on your page, then why don't you do it with Javascript?

Comment: `content` mostly works for `:before` and `:after`, so I think `:placeholder` may not have `content` support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`content` is intended to be used with pseudo-elements `before` & `after`.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

is there some particular reason why you'd want to have it set through css and not through html/javascript?

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity. I can do it with JavaScript. Just asking.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you use Javascript for this with jQuery:

```
$('#search-input').attr('placeholder', 'Search for Stuff');
```

or pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('search-input').setAttribute('placeholder', 'Search for Stuff');
```

Comment: I wonder what is the reason for someone to give a negative vote on this anwser? Please elaborate.

Comment: you probably missed the *with CSS*

Comment: I didn't miss that part, I just suggested to use javascript, because it's most probabl not doable with CSS and I don't think it's recommended to use CSS for content manipulation.